# Function can print the right value but not return it

Tags: java, function, return

```java
ArrayList<Muchie> binarySearchLant(Punct p, int l, int r, ArrayList<ArrayList<Muchie>> lanturi) {
        int m = (l+r)/2;
        if (l < r) {
            Object[] lant = lanturi.get(m).toArray();
            Punct[] puncte = new Punct[lant.length+1];
            Muchie muchie = null;
            for (int i=0;i<lant.length;i++)
                puncte[i] = ((Muchie)(lant[i])).getPI();
            puncte[puncte.length-1] = ((Muchie)lant[lant.length-1]).getPS();
            int abs = Math.abs(Arrays.binarySearch(puncte, p));
            if (abs <= 1)
                muchie = (Muchie)lant[0];
            if (abs >= puncte.length)
                muchie = (Muchie)lant[lant.length - 1];
            if (abs > 1 && abs < puncte.length)
                muchie = (Muchie)lant[abs-2];
            System.out.println(lanturi.get(m));
            if (this.calcDet(muchie.getPI(), p, muchie.getPS()) > 0)
                this.binarySearchLant(p, m+1, r, lanturi);
            else
                this.binarySearchLant(p, l, m-1, lanturi);
        } else {
            return lanturi.get(m);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This function is basically an adapted binary search but for my problem. I don't think the explanation of the code is necessary as that is NOT my issue. My issue is that if I try to return `lanturi.get(m)` the return value of this function is always null, but if I instead make the binary search function void and change `return lanturi.get(m);` to `System.out.println(lanturi.get(m));` it prints exactly what it is supposed to. I really can't understand why.

Comment: In the first if-part there is missing a return of a recursive call to binarySearch, and hence it reachtes the last return null.

Comment: Ok, I'm actually embarrassed...

Comment: I am weekly embarrassed.